# Does 'Priority Queue' data structure fits to SET Theory?

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue, abstract-data-type

Does the Priority Queue data structure follow the set theory in terms of the uniqueness of its elements in its content?

I mean you cannot put a duplicate of an entity in the priority queue. -whereas you can put many duplicates of same value in a queue:

```
    Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
    q.Enqueue(5);
    q.Enqueue(5);
    q.Enqueue(3);
```

Can yo confirm if this is correct or incorrect, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the implementation, but most priority queues that I've seen allow duplicate keys/priorities. Note that if a priority queue enforces unique keys, that probably means that priorities, not values, will be unique.